# Azure Service Bus Topic Requests vs Messages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I need help interpreting these graphs:
[image]

It has 0 subscriptions. Does this mean nothing is reading from this topic?

Looking at the Messages graph, in the last 30 days, no messages have been received or read from this topic.

Why are there 368 incoming and successful requests, if nothing is being written to/read from this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an expected behavior for incoming requests.

Even though there are no messages sending to `service bus`, the `Scale Unit`(which hosts the service bus) will always send requests to `service bus` for `health check` / `polling` purpose(I'm not very sure about this, just a guess).

You can check this behavior by setting `Diagnostic settings` for `azure service bus`. For example, you can send the `OperationalLogs` to `azure blob storage` or `azure log analytics`, then you can check the `OperationalLogs` later. Like below(here, I send the logs to `azure blob storage`):

[image]

Then wait for a few minutes, go to the `azure blob storage` -> find the container named `insights-logs-operationallogs` which is auto-created, and it's structrue like  `SUBSCRIPTIONS / RESOURCEGROUPS / PROVIDERS /  NAMESPACES / year / month / hour / day / hour` -> then there should be an append blob similar to `PT1H.json`. You can download it and check the logs there. The log looks like below:

[image]

Inside the log, you can see that the `caller` **rpfrontdoor** continues sending requests to `service bus`.

Added a detailed log message here:

> { "Environment": "PROD", "Region": "Central US", "ScaleUnit":
> "PROD-DM2-006", "ActivityId": "e203b024-48dc-44d3-b5eb-e345c090676c",
> "EventName": "Retrieve Namespace", "resourceId":
> "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/xxx/RESOURCEGROUPS/xxx/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.SERVICEBUS/NAMESPACES/HDUAIDHWUAYDQHD",
> "SubscriptionId": "xxx", "EventTimeString": "4/15/2021 9:22:27 AM
> +00:00", "EventProperties": "{"SubscriptionId":"xxxx","Namespace":"hduaidhwuaydqhd","Via":"https://hduaidhwuaydqhd.servicebus.windows.net/$Resources/topics?api-version=2017-04&$skip=0&$top=100","TrackingId":"e203b024-48dc-44d3-b5eb-e345c090676c_M7SN1_M7SN1_G7"}",
> "Status": "Succeeded", "Caller": "rpfrontdoor", "category":
> "OperationalLogs"}

Comment: This would be why the Requests graph is so periodic, right?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner yes, it is.